# Is it normal that adding a float array on a view buffer does not increase position?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

As titled, this code:

```
    ByteBuffer vertexBuffer = GLBuffers.newDirectByteBuffer(3*Float.BYTES+3*Byte.BYTES);
    System.out.println(vertexBuffer.toString());
    vertexBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(new float[]{1,2,3});
    System.out.println(vertexBuffer.toString());
    vertexBuffer.put(new byte[]{0,1,2});
    System.out.println(vertexBuffer.toString());
```

Prints out the following:

```
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=15 cap=15]
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=15 cap=15]
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=3 lim=15 cap=15]
```

But, in theory, I'd expect the first `put` on my view buffer to increase the position from 0 to 3, and the second `put` from 3 to 6, in order to get something like this:

```
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=15 cap=15]
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=3 lim=15 cap=15]
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=6 lim=15 cap=15]
```

The api doc says:

> public final FloatBuffer put(float[] src) Relative bulk put
>   method  (optional operation). This method transfers the entire content
>   of the given source float array into this buffer. An invocation of
>   this method of the form dst.put(a) behaves in exactly the same way as
>   the invocation
>        dst.put(a, 0, a.length)

If we go to see the invocation it mentions

> public FloatBuffer put(float[] src, int offset, int length) Relative
>   bulk put method  (optional operation). This method transfers floats
>   into this buffer from the given source array. If there are more floats
>   to be copied from the array than remain in this buffer, that is, if
>   length > remaining(), then no floats are transferred and a
>   BufferOverflowException is thrown. Otherwise, this method copies
>   length floats from the given array into this buffer, starting at the
>   given offset in the array and at the current position of this buffer.
>   **The position of this buffer is then incremented by length.** In other
>   words, an invocation of this method of the form dst.put(src, off, len)
>   has exactly the same effect as the loop
>        for (int i = off; i < off + len; i++)
>            dst.put(a[i]);

It clearly says the position is gonna be increment..

Is it normal or am I missing anything?

Edit: Same behaviour with:

```
ByteBuffer vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3*Float.BYTES+3*Byte.BYTES);
```

Comment: May be it's a particular problem of `GLBuffers.newDirectByteBuffer` implementation? What it is?

Comment: It's the `jogl` util to allocate buffer, anyway it's not that, let me update the question

Comment: The Javadoc for view buffers clearly states that they maintain their own position and limit.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, lunch break :), let me check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok, because actually `position` is increased in another object, which's reference you get when invoke `vertexBuffer.asFloatBuffer()`.

In other words, if you change your code to:

```
    FloatBuffer floatBuffer = vertexBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    floatBuffer.put(new float[]{1, 2, 3});
    System.out.println(floatBuffer.toString());
```

you will get:

```
java.nio.ByteBufferAsFloatBufferB[pos=3 lim=3 cap=3]
```